# Scraping results from multiple pages into one item using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

How can I scrape results from multiple pages into one item using Scrapy?

The pages that should be considered:

- an original page `o` (e.g. given by `start_requests()`)
- all pages `url` in `urls`, where `urls` is a field created by scraping `o` according to `parse()`.

Note that `urls` for different `o` might not be disjoint.

##### Specific example

I have a spider that yields the following fields for an item `i`, i.e. for a scraped page:

- `id`
- `prio`
- `urls`

`urls` is a list of urls, and for each url (that is not dead) I want to scrape some information from url to extend `i`'s fields

- `image_list`
- `head_list`

Finally, I want to filter the resulting items so that for each `id`, only the item with the highest `prio` is kept.

##### What I have tried

Since I have read that all scraping should be done inside a spider (as opposed to e.g. inside an items pipeline component), I thought the best approach would be to separate the scraping from the post processing by:

1. use a spider that collects all data from a start page, parses the data via `parse` into `i`, and then calls `response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_given_url, meta={'item':i})` for each url in `i`'s `urls`
2. `parse_given_url` will extract the metadata into `i`, parse the given url, and add `image_list` and `head_list` to `i`
3. do all post processing (merge and filter) on all the scraped data via item pipeline components to get all final items.

A minimal reproducible example of my approach:

```
import scrapy

class Minimal(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "minimal"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.arztsuche-bw.de/index.php?suchen=1&id_fachgruppe=441&arztgruppe=facharzt&plz=761&direction=ASC'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, method="POST", callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for office in response.css('li.row.resultrow.even') + response.css('li.row.resultrow.odd'):
            full_name = office.css('dd.name dl').xpath('string(.//dt[1])').get()
            contact_selectors = office.css('dd.adresse dl dd')
            urls = contact_selectors.xpath('.//a[@title="Homepage aufrufen"]/@href').getall()
            office_data = {
                'name': full_name,
                'url': urls,
            }
            if urls:
                for url in urls:
                    yield response.follow(url, callback=self.parse_hp, meta={'item':office_data})
            else:
                yield office_data

    def parse_hp(self, response):
        office_data = response.meta['item']

        return {
            **office_data,
            'hp_head': response.xpath('//h1/text()').get(),
            'hp_logo_image': response.xpath('//img/@src').get(),
        }
```

However, since the `urls` fields from different items are not disjoint, some requests from `response.follow_all()` calls are dropped, so resulting items are missing. I could add the argument `dont_filter=True` to the `response.follow_all()` calls, but then a url might be scraped multiple times, which I would like to avoid. Thus I have the feeling my approach is not right one.

Comment: Why the -1 and close vote? Please explain in a comment to give me the chance to improve the question.

Comment: You need to include a minimal reproducible example in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Do that, edit it accordingly, ask a focused (programming) question, and I will vote to reopen, and maybe answer it as well. And no, I didn't downvote you :)

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus thanks for the feedback (+1). I have rewritten the question to be more focused, and now also added a minimal reproducible example (which unfortunately still has more LOCs than I hoped for, but this was necessary to still work sufficiently well for areal website).

Comment: Just to be able to wrap my head around this: you're scraping medical cabinets list (4 pages), and for each of them, you're following the link to their own website, and get the title and image source? Aren't those supposed to be all websites with a different design, where page title is not necessarily a `<h1>` tag, and maybe the logo is not the first image in page?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus you are absolutely correct. I use some (still suboptimal) heuristics to get the title and logo, and simplified those to the simplest case for the minimal reproducible example since those heuristics are not part of my question...

Comment: Ok, it seems that there isn't another vote to reopen (you need 3 for that). Nonetheless, from what I can understand, your main issue is how to transfer information from  the first parse function to the next one, and obtain an item (dictionary) containing both info from the initial page, as well as from subsequent page crawled). See this pastebin I created for you: https://pastebin.com/VL7rEVNc .It still requires some debugging to move through all offices, nonetheless it should demonstrate how you can combine information from both `arztsuche-bw.de` and the respective clinics websites.

Comment: Also, Scrapy will automatically drop the duplicate urls by default, so it won't follow a url more than once.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus yes, I have added the argument `dont_filter=True` to `response.follow_all()` so the duplicate urls are no longer dropped. I also added `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True` so that the duplicate urls are not requested multiple times.

Comment: Try it now, I did some further debugging, now it will return 56 out of 63 doctors. Of course, it needs yet further debugging, to get them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine info from the main website with info picked from individual clinics' websites, you can do the following (EDIT: included `custom_settings`,as well as redirection to 'google.com' for the ones without a website, and now it will yield 56 results out of 63 - needs further debugging):

```
import scrapy
from german_medical.items import GermanMedicalItem

class DoctorsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'doctors'
    custom_settings = {
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter',
    }
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = ['https://www.arztsuche-bw.de/index.php?suchen=1&offset=0&id_z_arzt_praxis=0&id_fachgruppe=441&id_zusatzbezeichnung=0&id_genehmigung=0&id_dmp=0&id_zusatzvertraege=0&id_sprache=0&vorname=&nachname=ohne+Titel+%28Dr.%29&arztgruppe=facharzt&geschlecht=alle&wochentag=alle&zeiten=alle&fa_name=&plz=761&ort=&strasse=&schluesselnr=&schluesseltyp=lanr7&landkreis=&id_leistungsort_art=0&id_praxis_zusatz=0&sorting=name&direction=ASC&checkbox_content=&name_schnellsuche=&fachgebiet_schnellsuche=']
    offset = 20
    def parse(self, response):
        doctor_cards = response.xpath('//ul[contains(@class, "resultlist")]/li[contains(@class, "resultrow")]')
        for d in doctor_cards:
            full_name = ' '.join(d.xpath('.//dd[@class="name"]/dl/dt/text()').extract())
            address = ', '.join(d.xpath('.//dd[@class="adresse"]/p[@class="anschrift-arzt"]/text()').extract()[1:])
            urls = [x for x in d.xpath('.//dd[@class="adresse"]/p[@class="anschrift-arzt"]/following-sibling::dl//a/@href').extract() if 'mailto:' not in x ]
            resp_meta = {
                'full_name': full_name,
                'address': address,
                'urls': urls 
            }
            if not urls:
                urls = ['https://google.com']
            for url in urls:
                print(url)    
                yield response.follow(url=url, callback = self.parse_doctor_clinik, meta = resp_meta)

        next_page = 'https://www.arztsuche-bw.de/index.php?suchen=1&offset=' + str(self.offset) + '&id_z_arzt_praxis=0&id_fachgruppe=441&id_zusatzbezeichnung=0&id_genehmigung=0&id_dmp=0&id_zusatzvertraege=0&id_sprache=0&vorname=&nachname=ohne+Titel+%28Dr.%29&arztgruppe=facharzt&geschlecht=alle&wochentag=alle&zeiten=alle&fa_name=&plz=761&ort=&strasse=&schluesselnr=&schluesseltyp=lanr7&landkreis=&id_leistungsort_art=0&id_praxis_zusatz=0&sorting=name&direction=ASC&checkbox_content=&name_schnellsuche=&fachgebiet_schnellsuche='
        print(next_page)
        if self.offset < 80:
            self.offset += 20
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
    
    def parse_doctor_clinik(self, response):
        items  = GermanMedicalItem()
        try:
            website_header = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get() if response.xpath('//h1/text()') else None
            logo_url = response.xpath('//img/@src').get() if response.xpath('//img/@src') else None
        except Exception as e:
            website_header = 'Not specified'
            logo_url = 'Not specified'
        items['full_name'] = response.request.meta['full_name']
        items['address'] = response.request.meta['address']
        items['office_urls'] = response.request.meta['urls']
        items['website_header'] = website_header
        items['logo_url'] = logo_url

        yield items
```

Your `items.py` file should look like:

```
# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class GermanMedicalItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    full_name = scrapy.Field()
    office_urls = scrapy.Field()
    address = scrapy.Field()
    website_header = scrapy.Field()
    logo_url = scrapy.Field()
```

Run with `scrapy crawl doctors -o doctors_germ.json`, and you get a json file like:

```
[
{"full_name": "Dr. med. Jan Gestrich Sprechstundenzeiten ", "address": "Zeppelinstr. 2, 76185 Karlsruhe, Ortsteil: Gr\u00fcnwinkel, Landkreis: Karlsruhe - Stadt", "office_urls": ["https://www.ka-nephrologie.de"], "website_header": "Diagnostik und Therapie in unserer Nephrologischen Praxis", "logo_url": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgAAIAAAUAAarVyFEAAAAASUVORK5CYII="},
{"full_name": "Dr. med. Martin Andre Sprechstundenzeiten ", "address": "S\u00fcdendstr. 47-49, 76137 Karlsruhe, Ortsteil: S\u00fcdweststadt, Landkreis: Karlsruhe - Stadt", "office_urls": ["https://www.nephrologie-karlsruhe.de"], "website_header": null, "logo_url": "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/689a07_b6517c8c92574851a08a4b37c9a23142~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_101,h_72,al_c,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/Logo_Nephro_neu.jpg"},
{"full_name": "Dr. med. Kathrin Drognitz Sprechstundenzeiten ", "address": "Moltkestr. 90, 76133 Karlsruhe, Ortsteil: Nordstadt, Landkreis: Karlsruhe - Stadt", "office_urls": ["https://www.klinikum-karlsruhe.de/einrichtungen/spezielle-medizinische-einrichtungen/"], "website_header": "Spezielle medizinische Einrichtungen", "logo_url": "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D'http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg'%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20100%20100'%2F%3E"},
{"full_name": "Dr. med. Thorsten Dorn Sprechstundenzeiten ", "address": "Kriegsstr. 140, 76133 Karlsruhe, Ortsteil: Innenstadt-West, Landkreis: Karlsruhe - Stadt", "office_urls": ["https://www.hormone-karlsruhe.de"], "website_header": null, "logo_url": "/templates/web_joomla_neu/images/spacer.gif"},
{"full_name": "Dr. med. Wilhelm Hausch Sprechstundenzeiten ", "address": "Lammstr. 21, 76133 Karlsruhe, Ortsteil: Innenstadt-West, Landkreis: Karlsruhe - Stadt", "office_urls": ["https://www.gastroenterologie-karlsruhe.de"], "website_header": "Herzlich Willkommen in der Praxis f\u00fcr Gastroenterologie am Ettlinger Tor.", "logo_url": "/assets/asset.babb34fd.png"},
{"full_name": "Dr. med. Norbert Bruhn Sprechstundenzeiten ", "address": "Gartenstr. 71, 76135 Karlsruhe, Ortsteil: S\u00fcdweststadt, Landkreis: Karlsruhe - Stadt", "office_urls": ["https://www.praxis-bruhn.com"], "website_header": null, "logo_url": "https://www.praxis-bruhn.com/s/img/emotionheader7307447.jpg?1472391703.667px.483px"},
{"full_name": "Dr. med. Kurt Beier Sprechstundenzeiten ", "address": "Ludwig-Erhard-Allee 24, 76131 Karlsruhe, Ortsteil: Innenstadt-Ost, Landkreis: Karlsruhe - Stadt", "office_urls": ["https://www.deRossi.de", "https://www.medGAIN.de"], "website_header": "\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\tmedGAIN | Praxis Dr. med. Thomas de Rossi und Kollegen\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t", "logo_url": "img/med_gain_logo.svg"},
{"full_name": "Dr. med. Kai Haberl Sprechstundenzeiten ", "address": "Waldstra\u00dfe 41-43, 76133 Karlsruhe, Ortsteil: Innenstadt-West, Landkreis: Karlsruhe - Stadt", "office_urls": ["https://www.kardiologie-waldstrasse.de"], "website_header": " Unser Team hei\u00dft Sie herzlich willkommen! ", "logo_url": "images/logo_kardiologie_karlsruhe.svg"},
{"full_name": "Dr. med. Lutz Krieglstein Sprechstundenzeiten ", "address": "Hans-Sachs-Str. 1, 76133 Karlsruhe, Ortsteil: Weststadt, Landkreis: Karlsruhe - Stadt", "office_urls": ["https://www.praxis-muehlburger-tor.de"], "website_header": "Gastroenterologische Gemeinschaftspraxis in Karlsruhe", "logo_url": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgAAIAAAUAAarVyFEAAAAASUVORK5CYII="},
{"full_name": "Dr. med. Mirko Krivokuca Sprechstundenzeiten ", "address": "Kaiserallee 30, 76185 Karlsruhe, Ortsteil: Weststadt, Landkreis: Karlsruhe - Stadt", "office_urls": ["https://www.kardiologie-musikerviertel.de"], "website_header": "Fieber\n?\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0 Husten?\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0 Atemwegsinfekt?", "logo_url": "https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/none/path/sb3d393a4e68b5222/image/i855f937e8779839c/version/1608138272/image.jpg"},
....
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1). This shows that first scraping everything, using `response.follow()` with the argument `meta`, and later on do all the post processing, is indeed the way to go. Since I want to filter in post processing according to my own rules, duplicate urls should not be dropped (also states as requirement in my question). Could you please add a solution for that? Do you think the best solution is via argument `dont_filter=True` and setting `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True`?

Comment: Also thanks a lot for all the selectors, yours are much better than mine :)

Comment: Which ones are the duplicate urls, @DaveFar? Do you mean, doctor listings with more than one (different) url? I'm genuinely confused.

Comment: There are multiple `doctor_card`s with the same singleton `urls` list. Thus all but the first `doctor_card` for a given singleton `urls` list will be dropped.

Comment: I'm ok with your edits, just bear in mind using list comprehension allows you to do stuff like `strip()` on individual elements (like x.strip() for x, or similar), resulting in complexity budget savings for post processing. @DaveFar